# What SO topics would you like to see discussed on the podcast?

Tags: discussion, podcast

As I've mentioned elsewhere, I'd like to hear more from Jeff and Joel (and particularly a proper back-and-forth discussion between them) about the purpose of the reputation cap, and why/whether a time-sensitive approach is the most effective one. Even if that doesn't result in any changes, I think it would be an interesting discussion. That's just an example though - this question *isn't* meant to be about reputation!

What other StackOverflow-related topics would you like to hear discussed on the podcast? Do you particularly like the SO-related stuff, or are you more interested in general tech stuff? (Of course it's quite possible that J&J are sick of meta discussions, and any answers here will be pointless - but that's a different matter.)

Note that there's a [separate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5097) dealing with potential podcast guests, so it's probably best to keep the discussion off that topic here.

Comment: Jon would be the one to want to get rid of the rep cap. Usually not a problem for me, but I wouldn't have a gripe about it if they did do away with it. It would be cool to see Jon go from 79.5K to 100K rep in one day.

Comment: @L.A.:He's already got >220K in theory, but doesn't want a recalc.

Comment: @LA: I originally filed a request for the rep cap to be changed to a per-item one long before I got to the #1 spot. My problem with it is philosophical, not personal injury. On SU, for instance, I suspect some users would gain *massively* due to a rep calc change, but I wouldn't - I've barely hit the rep cap most days, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I have never once actually listened to the podcasts (I do read the recaps the comment discussions on the blog, though). If there was discussion concerning the rep limits and such I think I would actually tune in.

I would definitely like to hear a serious discussion concerning the possibilities of a version of StackExchange being released as an open source project and the possibilities for that as far as what types of branches could be made from it. I think this was discussed before, but it was more along the lines of a proprietary vs. foss debate.

**Edit** Another topic which I would absolutely love to hear about is Jeff & Joel's take on the pony meme that I have managed to unleash on this once innocent landscape.

Comment: Listen to the last couple of episodes - they have stuff about Open Source possibilities. It's generally a really good listen.

Comment: Somehow, I don't want to see the source code of SO, as I fear it has some relation with a site called Coding Horror :)

Comment: Agreed.  The topics are fairly diverse although usually related to SO, and they have original, unscripted, substantial debates between J&J on genuine SO development issues (both software and biz) that can be both entertaining, thought provoking and occasionally shocking.

Comment: Jon Skeet: I'll have to give them a listen then.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't listened to any podcast nor read the blog, but I'd like discussions about these:

- Why every second response to meta questions involves "by-design" (declines or as explanation), without any explanation or a link to the explanation?
- What would be the money to sell the entire SO, so the new owner can go ahead and fix the problems?
- When will we have SO 2.0?
- Besides the names and color schemes, what are the differences between the family sites that made them to be created and developed separately?
- Proofs, proofs, proofs, and transparency to validate the proofs?
- During SO design and development, was there any international involvement?

If my questions have been already discussed, please feel free to comment in the links to them.

Comment: -1, I guessed so. What year is it btw?

Comment: SO is already on V2.0. You can upvote comments dude!