# Podcast Suggestions for Episode #63

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, podcast

Following [Ólafur's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8701/why-not-use-so-for-the-so-podcast). This initiative is not endorsed,or suggested by the SO Team. I simply thought it would be interesting to see what you guys would like to hear discussed in next weeks episode, and maybe vote-up topics/questions you like from others.

Who knows, maybe this will become a regular thing?

Comment: This should prob be CW, as Olafur suggested in his question! (I'm not normally CW police, though)

Comment: Maybe you should remove the "Episode #63" from the title, as this topic would no longer be relevant once that episode airs.

Comment: Wiki      'fied.

Comment: @Kyle, I thought about that but figured it would be better to leave this specific, and have it locked once the program airs. Then start another for #64 (assuming this one gives us a good experience).

Comment: @Jonathan That was my idea as well. So I agree with that.

Comment: @Jonathan: Sure, that makes sense, but I have a feeling that 95% of the ideas for one week won't get done and will be suggested for the next week.

Comment: @Kyle if it would be one topic, then it would be way to large. If your thing didn't get answered then to bad. If you really want to see it answered. Ask again next week.

Answer (score 6):

Interview a top-10 member (or any *really* active member) for 10 minutes. Ask them about how Stackoverflow is integrated into their life. What type of browsing habits they have, and how they've grown to use the engine.

Answer (score 3):

Talk about mistakes in Programming and tie that with mistakes done with SO and how they were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet asked this also at

[What SO topics would you like to see discussed on the podcast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6912/what-so-topics-would-you-like-to-see-discussed-on-the-podcast)

so its obviously a good question :-)

I'd like to see more discussions on the impact of "the Cloud" and how its evolving. Maybe talk to ***[Nicholas Carr](http://www.roughtype.com/)*** on his views of what he's seen since he published "the Big Switch". He was mentioned and referenced in [Podcast #9](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/podcast-9/)

Comment: > so its obviously a good question.

not _obviously_